# What does mask r-cnn's AP, AP50, AP70 mean?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, convolution, deconvolution, caffe2

I'm novice on r-cnn.

There are term AP, AP50, AP75 on mask r-cnn paper.
50, 75 is small postfix, but I can't make it small, sorry.
Anyway the paper says it is averaged over IOU thresholds.
For AP50, only candidates over 50% region comparing ground truth are counted,
and for AP75 only candidate over 75% are counted. Then what is empty AP? I knew AP use 70% IoU threshold, but it wouldn't. Because just AP is lower then AP75.

And additionally, there are another terms I don't understand well.
They are APs, m, L. I know they mean small, medium, large. Then is there any criteria how big they are. Just saying small, medium, large makes me little bit confused.

Answer (score 7):

I found them from below:
http://cocodataset.org/#detections-eval

#### Average Precision (AP):

```
AP         % AP at IoU=.50:.05:.95 **(primary challenge metric)**
APIoU=.50   % AP at IoU=.50 (PASCAL VOC metric)
APIoU=.75   % AP at IoU=.75 (strict metric)
```

#### AP Across Scales:

```
APsmall    % AP for small objects: area < 322
APmedium   % AP for medium objects: 322 < area < 962
APlarge    % AP for large objects: area > 962
```

#### Average Recall (AR):

```
ARmax=1    % AR given 1 detection per image
ARmax=10   % AR given 10 detections per image
ARmax=100  % AR given 100 detections per image
```

#### AR Across Scales:

```
ARsmall    % AR for small objects: area < 322
ARmedium   % AR for medium objects: 322 < area < 962
ARlarge    % AR for large objects: area > 962
```